# How to merge lines together that are separeted by =====

Tags: regex, wordpress, text, filter, formatting

I'd like to filter a text, but I can't find a way to do it. 
My text is like this:

```
name: name1
house: house1
nationality: nationality1
=============================
name: name2
house: house2
nationality: nationality2
=============================
name: name3
house: house3
nationality: nationality3
```

And I would like to make it like that:

```
name: name1 house: house1 nationality: nationality1
=============================
name: name2 house: house2 nationality: nationality2
=============================
name: name3 house: house3 nationality: nationality3
```

Can it be done with Notepad++? 
Or is there another way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notepad++, try this Regex:

`(?<!=)[\r\n]+(?!=)`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wk2C7X/2)

**EXPLANATION:**

- `(?<!=)` - A negative lookbehind to find the position which is not immediately preceded with a `=`
- `[\r\n]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a newline character or a carriage-return immediately after the position found in previous step
- `(?!=)` - Negative lookahead to validate that the current match is not immediately followed by a `=`

**OUTPUT:**

Before Replacing:

[image]

After Replacing with a space:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If there are no "normal" lines ending or beginning with "=", replacing `([^=])\n([^=])`
with `\1 \2` (or `$1 $2`, depends on the engine) should work.

`[^=]` means "any character that isn't an equals sign", parentheses make sure we can use that character in our replacement and `\n` is a line break.

Since it won't match on the line breaks surrounding the separator, it will leave those alone.